# array_key_exists works properly when method is called direct, but not when through another method

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble in finding out why the code extract below does not do what I expect. When passing a setting string immediately to `settingIsProtected` the function returns correctly if a setting is protected (has leading underscore in the data array). But when the method is called through `getAll` if never gets past the first if statement.

Thoughts much appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php
class Config
{

    private static $data = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        '_baz' => 'qux'
    );

    public static function getAll($filterProtected = TRUE)
    {
        if ($filterProtected == TRUE) {
            $filtered = array();
            foreach (self::$data as $key => $value) {
                if (self::settingIsProtected($key) == TRUE) {
                    $filtered[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
            return $filtered;
        } else {
            return self::$data;
        }
    }

    public static function settingIsProtected($key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$data)) {
            return FALSE;
        } else if (array_key_exists('_' . $key, self::$data)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

}

var_dump(Config::settingIsProtected('foo'));    // prints false
var_dump(Config::settingIsProtected('baz'));    // prints true
var_dump(Config::getAll(FALSE));                // prints an array with foo and _baz
var_dump(Config::getAll(TRUE));                 // prints empty array
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to self::settingIsProtected($key) in getAll() will always return false, because the key being passed to it is '_baz'... and the array_key_exists($key, self::$data) in settingIsProtected() will identify this as existing (because it does exist), and return FALSE.

Modify the

```
if (self::settingIsProtected($key) == TRUE)
```

in getAll() to

```
if (self::settingIsProtected(trim($key,'_')) == TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first return statement within `settingIsProtected()` from `return FALSE;` to

```
return ($key[0] === '_');
```

This means that if the key, as passed in to the method, exists in the array; and it starts with an underscore then return `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

In `getAll(TRUE)`, you loop over all the keys in $data, which means in `settingIsProtected($key)` you're checking variable __baz in the bit

```
} else if (array_key_exists('_' . $key, self::$data)) {
```

Try to put an echo $key in settingIsProtected and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It won't actually get to the elseif, because it will always matchj the if test as true

Comment: Ahh you're right. It will always return false in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

To test if `baz` is a protected key, you would do `settingIsProtected('baz')`. However, `getAll` iterates on the keys of `$data`, so it does `settingIsProtected('_baz')`. That is the slight problem.